# Calculate the sum of the differences between all dates within an expanding window of dates

Tags: python, pandas

The `output` column below is what I'm trying to calculate and the `diffs` column is an explanation of the differences that are summed to calculate `output`.

```
+------------+--------+-------------+
|       date | output |    diffs    |
+------------+--------+-------------+
| 01/01/2000 |        |             |
| 10/01/2000 |      9 | [9]         |
| 20/01/2000 |     29 | [10, 19]    |
| 25/01/2000 |     44 | [5, 15, 24] |
+------------+--------+-------------+
```

I've thought about using `rolling` and then creating a new column within each window for the diffs based on the last record in the current window and then summing these. However, `rolling` doesn't seem to have the ability to fix at the beginning of a DataFrame. I suppose I could calculate the difference between the minimum and maximum dates and use this as the rolling period but that seems hacky.

I've also looked at `expanding` but I couldn't see a way of creating new diffs as the window expanded.

Is there a non-loop, hopefully vectorisable, solution to this?

Here's the DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'date': (
            dt.datetime(2000, 1, 1), dt.datetime(2000, 1, 10),
            dt.datetime(2000, 1, 20), dt.datetime(2000, 1, 25),
        ),
        'output': (np.NaN, 9, 29, 44),
    }
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for output, try:

```
datediff = df.date.diff()/pd.Timedelta('1D')

df['output'] = (datediff * np.arange(len(df))).cumsum()
```

Output:

```
        date  output
0 2000-01-01     NaN
1 2000-01-10     9.0
2 2000-01-20    29.0
3 2000-01-25    44.0
```

I'll leave the it to you to work out the logic behind.

Comment: `datediff = df.date.diff().dt.days` might be less confusing

Comment: @Quang Hang - thanks a million for this. The use of `np.arange` is really clever :) I don't suppose I could trouble you to ask how I would raise a constant to the power of each of the diffs and then sum the total? According to my manual calcs this should return `[NaN, 0.387420, 0.483764, 0.876148]`. My hunch is that this won't be easily possible given the way the `cumsum` works :(

Comment: Are you asking about [ewm](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ewm.html)?

Comment: Hey. I'm going to have to be a little careful here because I'm not even close to being a mathematician :) I 'think' this is the sort of thing I'm looking for but because I'm looking at a sum then ewm won't work for me. However, I have found a post that has given me a lead! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33294489/pandas-exponentially-decaying-sum-with-variable-weights. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Using `numpy` broadcasting without looping:

```
i = df.date.dt.day.values
j = np.arange(len(df))

df['output'] = np.triu(np.where((j < j[:, None]), i, (i - i[:, None]))).sum(axis = 0)
```